# How do I add autocompletion entry to my already tkinter project

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, software-design

I'm working on a Tkinter project, I'm done and all is working but I wanted to add an autocompletion Listbox to one of my entries so I cloned one from github but I can't seem to make it work...Anytime I run it opens two windows with the widget on top of my project instead of being on the project itself as an entry

I want the Autocomplete Entry to work on the "entername_e" Entry.
This is the GUI of my project:

```
 class Application:
        def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):                
            self.master = master
            #frame
            self.left = Frame(master, width=800, height=768, bg='white')
            self.left.pack(side=LEFT)

            self.right = Frame(master, width=566, height=768, bg='lightblue')
            self.right.pack(side=RIGHT)

            #components
            self.heading = Label(master, text= "Quame Supermarket", font=('arial 40 bold'), bg='white')
            self.heading.place(x=0, y=0)

            self.date_l = Label(self.right, text="Today's Date: "+str(date), font=('arial 14 bold'), bg='lightblue', fg='white')
            self.date_l.place(x=0, y=0)

            #table invoice=========================
            self.tproduct = Label(self.right, text="Products", font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='lightblue', fg='white')
            self.tproduct.place(x=0, y=60)

            self.tquantity = Label(self.right, text="quantity", font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='lightblue', fg='white')
            self.tquantity.place(x=200, y=60)

            self.tamount = Label(self.right, text="amount", font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='lightblue', fg='white')
            self.tamount.place(x=400, y=60)

            #enter stuff
            self.enterid = Label(self.left, text="Enter Product's ID", font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='white')
            self.enterid.place(x=0, y=80)

            self.enteride = Entry(self.left, width=25, font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='lightblue')
            self.enteride.place(x=260, y=80)
            self.enteride.focus()

            self.entername = Label(self.left, text="Enter Product's Name", font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='white')
            self.entername.place(x=0, y=150)

            self.entername_e = Entry(self.left, width=25, font=('arial 18 bold'), bg='lightblue')
            self.entername_e.place(x=260, y=150)

            #button 
            self.search_btn = Button(self.left, text="Search by Id(Right)", width=20, height=2, bg='orange', command=self.ajax1)
            self.search_btn.place(x=600, y=80)

            self.search_btn = Button(self.left, text="Search by Name", width=20, height=2, bg='orange', command=self.ajax2)
            self.search_btn.place(x=600, y=150)

            self.clear_btn = Button(self.left, text="Clear All", width=20, height=2, bg='green', fg='white', command=self.clear)
            self.clear_btn.place(x=600, y=490)

            #fill it later by the fucntion ajax
            self.productname = Label(self.left, text="", font=('arial 27 bold'), bg='white', fg='green')
            self.productname.place(x=0, y=250)

            self.pprice = Label(self.left, text="", font=('arial 27 bold'), bg='white', fg='green')
            self.pprice.place(x=0, y=290)

            #total label
            self.total_l = Label(self.right, text="Total", font=('arial 40 bold'), bg='lightblue', fg='green')
            self.total_l.place(x=0, y=600)
root = Tk()
b = Application(root)

root.geometry("1366x768+0+0")
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code I took from github:

```
class AutocompleteEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, autocompleteList, *args, **kwargs):

        # Listbox length
        if 'listboxLength' in kwargs:
            self.listboxLength = kwargs['listboxLength']
            del kwargs['listboxLength']
        else:
            self.listboxLength = 8

        # Custom matches function
        if 'matchesFunction' in kwargs:
            self.matchesFunction = kwargs['matchesFunction']
            del kwargs['matchesFunction']
        else:
            def matches(fieldValue, acListEntry):
                pattern = re.compile('.*' + re.escape(fieldValue) + '.*', re.IGNORECASE)
                return re.match(pattern, acListEntry)

            self.matchesFunction = matches


        Entry.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.focus()

        self.autocompleteList = autocompleteList

        self.var = self["textvariable"]
        if self.var == '':
            self.var = self["textvariable"] = StringVar()

        self.var.trace('w', self.changed)
        self.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
        self.bind("<Up>", self.moveUp)
        self.bind("<Down>", self.moveDown)

        self.listboxUp = False

    def changed(self, name, index, mode):
        if self.var.get() == '':
            if self.listboxUp:
                self.listbox.destroy()
                self.listboxUp = False
        else:
            words = self.comparison()
            if words:
                if not self.listboxUp:
                    self.listbox = Listbox(width=self["width"], height=self.listboxLength)
                    self.listbox.bind("<Button-1>", self.selection)
                    self.listbox.bind("<Right>", self.selection)
                    self.listbox.place(x=self.winfo_x(), y=self.winfo_y() + self.winfo_height())
                    self.listboxUp = True

                self.listbox.delete(0, END)
                for w in words:
                    self.listbox.insert(END,w)
            else:
                if self.listboxUp:
                    self.listbox.destroy()
                    self.listboxUp = False

    def selection(self, event):
        if self.listboxUp:
            self.var.set(self.listbox.get(ACTIVE))
            self.listbox.destroy()
            self.listboxUp = False
            self.icursor(END)

    def moveUp(self, event):
        if self.listboxUp:
            if self.listbox.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

            if index != '0':                
                self.listbox.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index) - 1)

                self.listbox.see(index) # Scroll!
                self.listbox.selection_set(first=index)
                self.listbox.activate(index)

    def moveDown(self, event):
        if self.listboxUp:
            if self.listbox.curselection() == ():
                index = '0'
            else:
                index = self.listbox.curselection()[0]

            if index != END:                        
                self.listbox.selection_clear(first=index)
                index = str(int(index) + 1)

                self.listbox.see(index) # Scroll!
                self.listbox.selection_set(first=index)
                self.listbox.activate(index) 

    def comparison(self):
        return [ w for w in self.autocompleteList if self.matchesFunction(self.var.get(), w) ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    autocompleteList = [ 'Dora Lyons (7714)', 'Hannah Golden (6010)', 'Walker Burns (9390)', 'Dieter Pearson (6347)', 'Allen Sullivan (9781)', 'Warren Sullivan (3094)', 'Genevieve Mayo (8427)', 'Igor Conner (4740)', 'Ulysses Shepherd (8116)', 'Imogene Bullock (6736)', 'Dominique Sanchez (949)', 'Sean Robinson (3784)', 'Diana Greer (2385)', 'Arsenio Conrad (2891)', 'Sophia Rowland (5713)', 'Garrett Lindsay (5760)', 'Lacy Henry (4350)', 'Tanek Conley (9054)', 'Octavia Michael (5040)', 'Kimberly Chan (1989)', 'Melodie Wooten (7753)', 'Winter Beard (3896)', 'Callum Schultz (7762)', 'Prescott Silva (3736)', 'Adena Crane (6684)', 'Ocean Schroeder (2354)', 'Aspen Blevins (8588)', 'Allegra Gould (7323)', 'Penelope Aguirre (7639)', 'Deanna Norman (1963)', 'Herman Mcintosh (1776)', 'August Hansen (547)', 'Oscar Sanford (2333)', 'Guy Vincent (1656)', 'Indigo Frye (3236)', 'Angelica Vargas (1697)', 'Bevis Blair (4354)', 'Trevor Wilkinson (7067)', 'Kameko Lloyd (2660)', 'Giselle Gaines (9103)', 'Phyllis Bowers (6661)', 'Patrick Rowe (2615)', 'Cheyenne Manning (1743)', 'Jolie Carney (6741)', 'Joel Faulkner (6224)', 'Anika Bennett (9298)', 'Clayton Cherry (3687)', 'Shellie Stevenson (6100)', 'Marah Odonnell (3115)', 'Quintessa Wallace (5241)', 'Jayme Ramsey (8337)', 'Kyle Collier (8284)', 'Jameson Doyle (9258)', 'Rigel Blake (2124)', 'Joan Smith (3633)', 'Autumn Osborne (5180)', 'Renee Randolph (3100)', 'Fallon England (6976)', 'Fallon Jefferson (6807)', 'Kevyn Koch (9429)', 'Paki Mckay (504)', 'Connor Pitts (1966)', 'Rebecca Coffey (4975)', 'Jordan Morrow (1772)', 'Teegan Snider (5808)', 'Tatyana Cunningham (7691)', 'Owen Holloway (6814)', 'Desiree Delaney (272)', 'Armand Snider (8511)', 'Wallace Molina (4302)', 'Amela Walker (1637)', 'Denton Tillman (201)', 'Bruno Acevedo (7684)', 'Slade Hebert (5945)', 'Elmo Watkins (9282)', 'Oleg Copeland (8013)', 'Vladimir Taylor (3846)', 'Sierra Coffey (7052)', 'Holmes Scott (8907)', 'Evelyn Charles (8528)', 'Steel Cooke (5173)', 'Roth Barrett (7977)', 'Justina Slater (3865)', 'Mara Andrews (3113)', 'Ulla Skinner (9342)', 'Reece Lawrence (6074)', 'Violet Clay (6516)', 'Ainsley Mcintyre (6610)', 'Chanda Pugh (9853)', 'Brody Rosales (2662)', 'Serena Rivas (7156)', 'Henry Lang (4439)', 'Clark Olson (636)', 'Tashya Cotton (5795)', 'Kim Matthews (2774)', 'Leilani Good (5360)', 'Deirdre Lindsey (5829)', 'Macy Fields (268)', 'Daniel Parrish (1166)', 'Talon Winters (8469)' ]
    def matches(fieldValue, acListEntry):
        pattern = re.compile(re.escape(fieldValue) + '.*', re.IGNORECASE)
        return re.match(pattern, acListEntry)

    root = Tk()
    entry = AutocompleteEntry(autocompleteList, root, listboxLength=6, width=32, matchesFunction=matches)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0)    
    Button(text='Python').grid(column=0)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you copy paste the Autocomplete code into the same file as the Application code?  If so the `if __name__ == '__main__'` will run and open a second Tk window.  Your code in the question won't run as there is no `date` or `self.ajax'n'` specified.  Can you reduce it to a window with an Autocomplete widget that demonstrates the problem? That will make it easier to answer.

Comment: The date, the ajax functions, and some other functions are part of it...don't want the code to look many here that is why I posted the vital parts(only the GUI as stated)...